# Published Winform Issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform app which reads sqlite database from a specific folder inside the machine's Document folder. So basically what I'm doing is importing data from mobile database to Sql server. The feature is running smoothly when debugging but after I published the app, installed it and run it, it throws sqlite.interop.dll is not found. I just downloaded x86 and x64 version of the dll and tried to inlcude it in the project and published again. But still the error persists.

My question: What could be the way to make the interop.dll be detected by the app?

Here's the code:

```
try
{
    var directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    var cn = "Data Source=" + directory + @"\Samplefolder\" + txtfilename.Text;

    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(cn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Tablr";

            using (SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    // getting values from dr and assigning to a property of a class
                }
            }
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Successful");
}
catch(Exception message)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Failed");
}
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: it throws object reference is not set to an instance of object

Comment: Add more debugging messages - get a more precise location of your error..

Comment: Just take a look at the StackTrace of the exception, this is where the exception comes from. where are "directory" and "txtfilename" declared ? could it be that "txtfilename" is null and accessing "txtfilename.Text" is the issue ?

Comment: @D.J. I Just edited my question.

Comment: Use `Path.Combine` for that directory stuff.  You cannot guarantee that there won't be a trailing '\' on the directory path, making your result invalid.

Comment: @DonBoitnott thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this after downloading both SQlite.Interop.dll x86 and x64 [here](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki). Then
created x86 and x64 folders in my project and placed the dlls into the folders correspondingly. Then edited the project properties and unchecked prefer 32-bit